# Best practice for comparing data between completers and non-completers?

Tags: time-series

I conducted a study which collected data on an intervention at 3 timepoints (pre, post, and one-week follow-up). There were some participants who dropped out between these 3 timepoints. Mainly between post and follow up.

It is best practice to check for differences between the participants who dropped out and those who completed all 3 stages? And if so, how?

Can you recommends any texts / resources that talk about how best to be deal with this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I ideally want to only use data from participants who completed the surveys at all 3 stages, for the most 'accurate' idea on how effective the intervention was. Just checking best practice for ensuring there were no significant differences (between both demographics and questionnaire responses) between those who dropped out vs those who completed all 3 stages? (Thanks!)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, when you say check for differences, what kind of differences you mean? What measures of participants you have for which you want to check the differences?

Comment: "I ideally want to only use data from participants who completed the surveys at all 3 stages, for the most 'accurate' idea on how effective the intervention was. " - you usually don't really want to do that. It's at best inefficient & often at high risk of bias (exactly not the "most accurate"). Best practice is to be clear on what your estimand is & then think how to estimate it. Simplistic solutions like completer-case often estimate weird quantities nobody is interested in, or nothing you can define (unless you make very strong assumptions e.g. missingness completely at random).